# How to clip (hide) the top half of a variable size TextBlock?

Tags: wpf, xaml, dynamic, textblock, clip

#### Background:

I have a basic `Clock CustomControl` that has a `DateTime` property that updates every second. Its default `ControlTemplate` is an `AnalogClockFace CustomControl`, but I also have a `DigitalClockFace CustomControl` that I can set as the `Template` value to have a digital display.

Recently, I thought I'd get adventurous and try making a `FlipDownClockFace CustomControl`, something like the old fashioned clocks where the numbers were split vertically half way up and displayed on rolls that would turn and flip down the next number as time progressed. Unfortunately I pretty much fell at the first, well second hurdle.

#### The problem:

To simplify this problem somewhat, I need to display two `TextBlock`s, with each displaying opposite halves of a `Text` value. By that I mean that one should display the top half of a `TextBlock.Text` value and the other one should display the bottom half of a `TextBlock.Text` value. Actually, I can clip (show) the top half of the `TextBlock` ok, it's displaying the bottom half that's the problem.

To be clear, I need the clip area to automatically resize to fit the `TextBlock` regardless of the `FontSize` value, so I cant just hard code a `Height` value. This question just relates to the clipping of the `TextBlock` and I will sort out all the `Transform Animation`s required for my `FlipDownClockFace` control later.

#### What I tried so far:

I managed to find out that I could use the `RenderedGeometry` property of a `Rectangle` element as the `TextBlock.Clip` value and so I thought that I could just pop a `Rectangle` in each half of a `Grid` to clip the two (overlayed) `TextBlock`s. This example shows a reconstruction of where it went wrong (the `DoubleDivisorConverter` just divides the data bound value (the `Height`) by the value of the `ConverterParameter` (in this case, 2.0)):

```
<Grid TextElement.FontSize="72">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Name="FirstValueBottomTextBox" Text="23" 
Clip="{Binding RenderedGeometry, ElementName=FirstValueBottomClipRectangle}" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue" />
    <Rectangle Name="FirstValueBottomClipRectangle" Grid.Row="1" Height="{Binding 
ActualHeight, ElementName=FirstValueBottomTextBox, Converter={StaticResource 
DoubleDivisorConverter}, ConverterParameter=2.0}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

Basically I worked out that the problem is that `RenderedGeometry` just uses the `Geometry` of the `Rectangle` and not the position, so this only ever clips (shows) the top half of the text, regardless of the actual position of the `Rectangle`. I couldn't find any way to move the clip area to the bottom to just show the bottom half of the text.

Before you suggest it, I can't do this either, as the `Rect.Height` property is unfortunately not a `DependencyProperty`:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Name="FirstValueBottomTextBox" Text="23"
VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue">
    <TextBlock.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry>
            <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                <Rect Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=
FirstValueBottomTextBox, Converter={StaticResource DoubleDivisorConverter}, 
ConverterParameter=2.0}" />
            </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
        </RectangleGeometry>
    </TextBlock.Clip>
</TextBlock>
```

So if anyone has any clues on how I can achieve this or if you need any more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it required to use the `Clip` functionality? Or is `OpacityMask` an option? The following code comes close to such a clock:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextElement.FontSize="36">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="UpperHalfStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="OpacityMask">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="White"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Transparent"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="LowerHalfStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="OpacityMask">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Transparent"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="White"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="1" Style="{StaticResource UpperHalfStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="1" Style="{StaticResource LowerHalfStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="0" Style="{StaticResource UpperHalfStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="0" Style="{StaticResource LowerHalfStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock Text=":"/>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="3" Style="{StaticResource UpperHalfStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="3" Style="{StaticResource LowerHalfStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="7" Style="{StaticResource UpperHalfStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="7" Style="{StaticResource LowerHalfStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I just overlay two `TextBlock` elements. The first one is only opaque in the upper half, while the second one is only opaque in the lower half. I also added a `Margin` to the lower half, so that it becomes clear that they are two different elements. I do not know the rest of your design, but I assume you will want to add borders around the numbers. For this, you might have to restrict the height of the elements somehow. Otherwise the borders will surround the whole `TextBlock` and not just the visible part.

Comment: +1 For an interesting option. However, if you set a `Background` on the first two `TextBlock`s, the centre position appears differently on those two `TextBlock`s compared with the others. I'm not sure if I can use this as I need the half way point to be exact and not to come from the `GradientPoint.Offset` as it does in your example. I will have a go when I get home tonight to see if it works with the animations.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I tried @gehho's suggestion and it worked fine for the most part. I built my `FlipDownClockFace` control and it all worked beautifully. The problem is that I'm a perfectionist and I wanted to make it look more realistic. I wanted to take a notch out of the corners of the `Border` elements that contain the `TextBlock`s but found that I couldn't do that using the `OpacityMask`.

So I went back to drawing board to investigate the `Clip` possibilities. In the end, I found a solution that enabled me to bind to the `Point`s of a `PathGeometry` used as the `Clip` shape using a custom `Converter`. The `Converter` takes in the `Width` and `Height` of the `Border` using a `MultiBinding` and converts them into a `Point` around its edge dependant on the `ConverterParameter`. It's pretty verbose (lots of code) but it works. For those interested, here is a trimmed down version:

```
<Border CornerRadius="{Binding BorderCornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Controls:FlipDownControl}}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
    <Border.Clip>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                <LineSegment>
                    <LineSegment.Point>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WidthAndHeightToPointConverter}" ConverterParameter="MiddleLeft">
                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}" Mode="OneWay" />
                            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}" Mode="OneWay" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </LineSegment.Point>
                </LineSegment>
                <LineSegment>
                    <LineSegment.Point>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WidthAndHeightToPointConverter}" ConverterParameter="MiddleRight">
                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}" Mode="OneWay" />
                            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}" Mode="OneWay" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </LineSegment.Point>
                </LineSegment>
                <LineSegment>
                    <LineSegment.Point>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WidthAndHeightToPointConverter}" ConverterParameter="BottomRight">
                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}" Mode="OneWay" />
                            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}" Mode="OneWay" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </LineSegment.Point>
                </LineSegment>
                <LineSegment>
                    <LineSegment.Point>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WidthAndHeightToPointConverter}" ConverterParameter="BottomLeft">
                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}" Mode="OneWay" />
                            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}" Mode="OneWay" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </LineSegment.Point>
                </LineSegment>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Border.Clip>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FrontValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Controls:FlipDownControl}}}" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
</Border>
```

Although this is the solution that I actually went with in the end, I'll leave the accepted answer with @gehho.